# Confusion with what exact code is called by event loop in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was learning Node.js and was watching video on what code is executed by event loop what not. So, here is the code snippet:

```
const fs = require('fs')
setTimeout(()=>console.log("Timer 1 finished"), 0);
setImmediate(()=>console.log("Immediate 1 finished"));

fs.readFile("test-file.txt", ()=>{
console.log("I/O finished");
console.log("----------");

setTimeout(()=>console.log("Timer 2 finished"), 0);
setTimeout(()=>console.log("Timer 3 finished"), 3000);
})

console.log("Hello from the top-level code")
```

The question is why setTimeout and setImmediate which are inside the callback of readFile are called in event loop BUT this code:

```
setTimeout(()=>console.log("Timer 1 finished"), 0);
    setImmediate(()=>console.log("Immediate 1 finished"));
```

is not run in event loop. This statement was made by author of Node.js course but he did not explain why. Is he wrong?

Comment: Could you post the source of the statement?

Comment: *"BUT this code...is not run in event loop"* Who told you that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, hey T.J, I was just watching course on udemy. Is he wrong?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @SAM - Because it was wrong. :-) Node.js has a more complex approach to running JavaScript code than I thought.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ok, all in all, please can you kindly tell if this code setTimeout(()=>console.log("Timer 1 finished"), 0);
    setImmediate(()=>console.log("Immediate 1 finished")); is run by event loop or not and briefly WHY?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, because I thought setTimeout(()=>console.log("Timer 1 finished"), 0);
    setImmediate(()=>console.log("Immediate 1 finished")); is sent to timer heap and on expiration of timer event loop takes the callbacks and run. Am I wrong

Comment: I think I've done that (now) in my corrected answer.

Answer (score 1):

> BUT this code...is not run in event loop

That's *literally* true, but it's almost a matter of semantics, and not really all that useful a differentiation to make. You can think of it as the top-level code is run on the first pass of the loop as though it were an instantly-fired timer callback. But the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) does say it's before, rather than during, the event loop:

> When Node.js starts, it initializes the event loop, **processes the provided input script** (or drops into the REPL, which is not covered in this document) which may make async API calls, schedule timers, or call `process.nextTick()`, then begins processing the event loop.

*(my emphasis)*

But again, that's a distinction that really makes very little difference.

Note that the code run that way is more than just the lines you quoted in that part of the question; more on that in a moment.

Mostly, you can think of all JavaScript code as running within an event loop, but Node.js makes the distinction above and also has `process.nextTick`, which [the documentation says](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick):

> ...is not technically part of the event loop. Instead, the `nextTickQueue` will be processed after the current operation is completed, regardless of the current phase of the event loop. Here, an operation is defined as a transition from the underlying C/C++ handler, and handling the JavaScript that needs to be executed.

That's a very Node.js-specific thing. And note that while they say it's technically outside the event loop, it still runs *during* the event loop, it's just that `nextTick` doesn't add a task to that main loop, it adds it to a different queue that is processed as soon as possible, regardless of what phase the event loop is in.

It's well worth reading that entire page for a better understanding.

About what code in your example is run when, the documentation linked above has this handy chart of the Node.js event loop:

```
   ┌───────────────────────────┐
┌─>│           timers          │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│  │     pending callbacks     │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│  │       idle, prepare       │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘      ┌───────────────┐
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐      │   incoming:   │
│  │           poll            │<─────┤  connections, │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘      │   data, etc.  │
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐      └───────────────┘
│  │           check           │
│  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
│  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
└──┤      close callbacks      │
   └───────────────────────────┘
```

...and gives this high-level overview of those phases:

- **timers**: this phase executes callbacks scheduled by `setTimeout()`
  and `setInterval()`.
- **pending callbacks**: executes I/O callbacks deferred to the next loop
  iteration.
- **idle, prepare**: only used internally.
- **poll**: retrieve new I/O events; execute I/O related callbacks (almost
  all with the exception of close callbacks, the ones scheduled by timers,
  and `setImmediate()`); node will block here when appropriate.
- **check**: `setImmediate()` callbacks are invoked here.
- **close callbacks**: some close callbacks, e.g. `socket.on('close', ...)`.

Based on that, here's how I think the code in your question gets run:

```
const fs = require('fs')                     // A
setTimeout(()=>                              // A
    console.log("Timer 1 finished")          //   B
, 0);
setImmediate(()=>                            // A
    console.log("Immediate 1 finished")      //     C
);

fs.readFile("test-file.txt", ()=>{           // A
    console.log("I/O finished");             //       D
    console.log("----------");               //       D
                                             //       D
    setTimeout(()=>                          //       D
        console.log("Timer 2 finished")      //   B
    , 0);
    setTimeout(()=>                          //       D
        console.log("Timer 3 finished")      //   B
    , 3000);                                 // A
})

console.log("Hello from the top-level code") // A
```

- A: During initial evaluation, "before" the event loop
- B: During the "timers" phase of the event loop
- C: During the "check" phase of the event loop
- D: During the "poll" phase (or possibly the "pending callbacks" phase of `readFile` defers the callback, I don't know which